# Filter an array in order to group items by data type

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got this:

```
var arr= ["three", "2", "five", "ten", "111", 1, 2, "forty", "33", 33];
```

I need it to be 2 new arrays
One with just the numbers, and the other with just the strings

Like this:

```
var strArr = ["three", "2", "five", "ten", "111","forty", "33"];
var numArr = [1, 2, 33];
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `typeof` **operator** in combination with `filter` method which accepts as parameter a **callback** function.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var arr= ["three", "2", "five", "ten", "111", 1, 2, "forty", "33", 33];
var numbers = arr.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item == 'number';
});
var strings = arr.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item == 'string';
});
console.log(numbers);
console.log(strings);
```

You can use `arrow` functions for a light solution.

```
['number', 'string'].map(i => arr.filter(a => typeof a == i));
```

Comment: thx, you helped me a lot, but can u explain me what filter does?

Comment: filter returns an array that only contains the items for wich the callback returns true

Comment: more info on filter -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr= ["three", "2", "five", "ten", "111", 1, 2, "forty", "33", 33];
var num=[];
var str=[];
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].includes('"') || arr[i].includes("'"))
           str.push(arr[i]);
    else
           num.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use create a function that checks if what you have given is a string or an integer and push the value to the right array.

I have not tested the code below but it should be a good starting place.

```
var arr= ["three", "2", "five", "ten", "111", 1, 2, "forty", "33", 33];

var strArr = [];
var numArr = [];

var arrayLength = arr.length();
// iterates trough the array
for (i; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    //Check if the given value in the array is string
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'string')
    {
        // adds the value you are checking to the strArr
        strArr.push(arr[i]);
    }

    //Check if the given value in the array is integer
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number' && isFinite(value))
    {
        // adds the value you are checking to the numArr
        numArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps